# Libraries for matrix rendering?

Tags: matrix, rendering, drawing

I have some trouble with matix rendering and processing. At first, I tried to use draw funciton in opencv. However, these drawing function looks not very efficient to me. For example, if I want to draw a polygon that contains arcs, I need to split arcs to lines.

I want to find a library can render matrix same as image rendering library, like anti-grain geometry (It only renders rgba and gray images).
For example, I want to render a 2x2 rectangle in a 3x3 matrix at point 1,1:
000     011
000  -> 011
000     000